# Mobile First Server installation error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

***Problem:***

Encountered this error when trying to install MobileFirst Server 7.1:

CRIMA1217E: Problem occurred during the execution of the /opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/WorklightServer/post-install.xml file.

This is the /opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/failed-install.log:

> Detected Java version: 1.7 in:
>   /opt/IBM/InstallationManager/eclipse/jre_7.0.9010.20151006_1234/jre
>   Detected OS: Linux parsing buildfile
>   /opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/WorklightServer/post-install.xml
>   with URI =
>   file:/opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/WorklightServer/post-install.xml
>   Project base dir set to:
>   /opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/WorklightServer parsing buildfile
>   jar:file:/opt/IBM/InstallationManager/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml
>   with URI =
>   jar:file:/opt/IBM/InstallationManager/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml
>   from a zip file  [macrodef] creating macro  ant-loop  [macrodef]
>   creating macro  copy-confidential-file  [macrodef] creating macro 
>   create-user-read-protected-dir  [macrodef] creating macro 
>   protect-allfiles-in-destination-dir  [macrodef] creating macro 
>   ant-escape  [macrodef] creating macro  argpart-escape  [macrodef]
>   creating macro  arg-escape Build sequence for target(s)
>   `ant-loop-callee' is [ant-loop-callee] Complete build sequence is
>   [ant-loop-callee, swallow-update-properties, init0, init1, init2,
>   init3, init, show-properties, unconfigure-shortcuts,
>   unconfigure-appcenter-appserver, uninstall-cleanup, uninstall,
>   cleanup-properties-file-for-appserver=was85liberty, cleanup, main,
>   ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part2.if-install,
>   configure-shortcuts, safe-uninstall,
>   ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part1,
>   ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part2.if-not-install,
>   ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part3.if-install-failed,
>   ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part3.if-not-install-failed,
>   ant-loop-inside-installation-manager,
>   cleanup-properties-file-for-appserver=tomcat, ant-loop-standalone,
>   configure-config-tool, safe-foo, restore-embedded-server-location,
>   delete-update-properties, configure-appcenter-database,
>   configure-appcenter-appserver, fix-permissions-in-scripts, install,
>   safe-install, protect-one-file,
>   cleanup-properties-file-for-appserver=was, ]
>
> ant-loop-callee: parsing buildfile
>   jar:file:/opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/WorklightServer/uninstall/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar!/net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml
>   with URI =
>   jar:file:/opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/WorklightServer/uninstall/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar!/net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml
>   from a zip file parsing buildfile
>   jar:file:/opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/WorklightServer/uninstall/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar!/net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml
>   with URI =
>   jar:file:/opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/WorklightServer/uninstall/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar!/net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml
>   from a zip file Project base dir set to:
>   /opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/WorklightServer   [antcall]
>   calling target(s) [install] in build file
>   /opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/WorklightServer/post-install.xml
>   parsing buildfile
>   /opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/WorklightServer/post-install.xml
>   with URI =
>   file:/opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/WorklightServer/post-install.xml
>   Project base dir set to:
>   /opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/WorklightServer  [macrodef]
>   creating macro  ant-loop  [macrodef] creating macro 
>   copy-confidential-file  [macrodef] creating macro 
>   create-user-read-protected-dir  [macrodef] creating macro 
>   protect-allfiles-in-destination-dir  [macrodef] creating macro 
>   ant-escape  [macrodef] creating macro  argpart-escape Override ignored
>   for property "argpart-escape.doublequote.escaped"  [macrodef] creating
>   macro  arg-escape Build sequence for target(s) `install' is
>   [restore-embedded-server-location, delete-update-properties, init0,
>   init1, show-properties, init2, init3, init,
>   configure-appcenter-database, configure-appcenter-appserver,
>   fix-permissions-in-scripts, configure-config-tool,
>   configure-shortcuts, cleanup, install] Complete build sequence is
>   [restore-embedded-server-location, delete-update-properties, init0,
>   init1, show-properties, init2, init3, init,
>   configure-appcenter-database, configure-appcenter-appserver,
>   fix-permissions-in-scripts, configure-config-tool,
>   configure-shortcuts, cleanup, install, swallow-update-properties,
>   unconfigure-shortcuts, unconfigure-appcenter-appserver,
>   uninstall-cleanup, uninstall,
>   cleanup-properties-file-for-appserver=was85liberty, main,
>   ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part2.if-install, safe-uninstall,
>   ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part1,
>   ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part2.if-not-install,
>   ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part3.if-install-failed,
>   ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part3.if-not-install-failed,
>   ant-loop-inside-installation-manager,
>   cleanup-properties-file-for-appserver=tomcat, ant-loop-standalone,
>   safe-foo, safe-install, protect-one-file, ant-loop-callee,
>   cleanup-properties-file-for-appserver=was, ]   [antcall] Entering
>   /opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/WorklightServer/post-install.xml...
>   Build sequence for target(s)`install' is
>   [restore-embedded-server-location, delete-update-properties, init0,
>   init1, show-properties, init2, init3, init,
>   configure-appcenter-database, configure-appcenter-appserver,
>   fix-permissions-in-scripts, configure-config-tool,
>   configure-shortcuts, cleanup, install] Complete build sequence is
>   [restore-embedded-server-location, delete-update-properties, init0,
>   init1, show-properties, init2, init3, init,
>   configure-appcenter-database, configure-appcenter-appserver,
>   fix-permissions-in-scripts, configure-config-tool,
>   configure-shortcuts, cleanup, install, swallow-update-properties,
>   unconfigure-shortcuts, unconfigure-appcenter-appserver,
>   uninstall-cleanup, uninstall,
>   cleanup-properties-file-for-appserver=was85liberty, main,
>   ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part2.if-install, safe-uninstall,
>   ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part1,
>   ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part2.if-not-install,
>   ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part3.if-install-failed,
>   ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part3.if-not-install-failed,
>   ant-loop-inside-installation-manager,
>   cleanup-properties-file-for-appserver=tomcat, ant-loop-standalone,
>   safe-foo, safe-install, protect-one-file, ant-loop-callee,
>   cleanup-properties-file-for-appserver=was, ]
>
> restore-embedded-server-location: [available] Unable to find file
>   server_rename.properties
>
> delete-update-properties: [available] Unable to find file
>   update.properties
>
> init0: [available] Found directory: /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty
>   [available] Unable to find dir
>   /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/features/com.ibm.ws.cim_7.0.0.0 [available]
>   Unable to find dir /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/wlp [available] Found
>   directory: /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/bin [available] Found file:
>   /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/bin/server
>
> init1:
>        [java] Executing '/opt/IBM/InstallationManager/eclipse/jre_7.0.9010.20151006_1234/jre/bin/java'
>   with arguments:
>        [java] '-classpath'
>        [java] '/opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/WorklightServer/worklight-ant-deployer.jar'
>        [java] 'com.ibm.worklight.config.helper.AntEscape'
>        [java] '={xyzzy}RF5WR3YIPKO7FELG71'
>        [java] 
>        [java] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
>        [java] not part of the command.
>        [java] Output redirected to property: appcenter-database.user.password.escaped
>        [java] Error redirected to property: AntEscape.appcenter-database.user.password.err [available] Unable to
>   find dir /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/wlp
>       [chmod] Executing 'chmod' with arguments:
>       [chmod] 'a+x'
>       [chmod] '/opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/ApplicationCenter/tools/android-sdk/bin.linux-x86/aapt'
>       [chmod] '/opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/ApplicationCenter/tools/android-sdk/bin.macosx-x86/aapt'
>       [chmod] '/opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/ApplicationCenter/tools/android-sdk/bin.windows-x86/aapt.exe'
>       [chmod] 
>       [chmod] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
>       [chmod] not part of the command.
>       [chmod] Applied chmod to 3 files and 0 directories.
>
> show-properties:
>        [echo] Ant called by IM:
>        [echo]       ${ant.version}=Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.3 compiled on February 26 2012
>        [echo]       ${java.home}=/opt/IBM/InstallationManager/eclipse/jre_7.0.9010.20151006_1234/jre
>        [echo]       ${java.fullversion}=JRE 1.7.0 IBM J9 2.6 Linux amd64-64 Compressed References 20150701_255667 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
>        [echo] J9VM - R26_Java726_SR9_20150701_0050_B255667
>        [echo] JIT  - tr.r11_20150626_95120.01
>        [echo] GC   - R26_Java726_SR9_20150701_0050_B255667_CMPRSS
>        [echo] J9CL - 20150701_255667
>        [echo]       ${output.file.name}=/var/ibm/InstallationManager/logs/mobilefirst-platform-server-install-20160117_1539a.log
>        [echo] 
>        [echo]       Variables set by im-custom-panels (list last updated on 2013-10-11):
>        [echo]       ${update.minimal}=false
>        [echo]       ${update.from.version}=
>        [echo]       ${im.package.group}=IBM MobileFirst Platform Server
>        [echo]       ${windows.common.configurationtool.shortcut.file}=
>        [echo]       ${windows.user.configurationtool.shortcut.file}=
>        [echo]       ${appserver.selection_}=was
>        [echo]       ${appserver.selection}=was85liberty
>        [echo]       ${appserver.was.installdir}=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/
>        [echo]       ${appserver.was.profile}=Liberty
>        [echo]       ${appserver.was.cell}=
>        [echo]       ${appserver.was.node}=
>        [echo]       ${appserver.was.scope}=
>        [echo]       ${appserver.was.serverInstance}=
>        [echo]       ${appserver.was.nd.cluster}=
>        [echo]       ${appserver.was.nd.node}=
>        [echo]       ${appserver.was.nd.server}=
>        [echo]       ${appserver.was.admin.name}=
>        [echo]       ${appserver.was.admin.password}=
>        [echo]       ${appserver.was.appcenteradmin.password}=
>        [echo]       ${appserver.was.serial}=
>        [echo]       ${appserver.was85liberty.installdir}=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/
>        [echo]       ${appserver.was85liberty.serverInstance_}=mfp
>        [echo]       ${appserver.was85liberty.backup.file}=
>        [echo]       ${appserver.was85liberty.backup.restore}=
>        [echo]       ${appserver.tomcat.installdir}=
>        [echo]       ${database.selection}=oracle
>        [echo]       ${database.preinstalled}=true
>        [echo]       ${database.derby.datadir}=
>        [echo]       ${database.db2.host}=
>        [echo]       ${database.db2.port}=
>        [echo]       ${database.db2.driver}=
>        [echo]       ${database.db2.appcenter.user.name}=
>        [echo]       ${database.db2.appcenter.user.password}=
>        [echo]       ${database.db2.appcenter.dbname}=
>        [echo]       ${database.db2.appcenter.schema}=
>        [echo]       ${database.mysql.host}=
>        [echo]       ${database.mysql.port}=
>        [echo]       ${database.mysql.driver}=
>        [echo]       ${database.mysql.appcenter.user.name}=
>        [echo]       ${database.mysql.appcenter.user.password}=
>        [echo]       ${database.mysql.appcenter.dbname}=
>        [echo]       ${database.oracle.driver}=/home/ubuntu/wkMacDownloads/JDBC11G/ojdbc6.jar
>        [echo]       ${database.oracle.appcenter.user.name_}=WLADMIN
>        [echo]       ${database.oracle.appcenter.user.name.jdbc_}=WLADMIN
>        [echo]       ${database.oracle.appcenter.user.password}={xyzzy}RF5WR3YIPKO7FELG71
>        [echo]       ${database.oracle.appcenter.jdbc.url}=jdbc:oracle:thin:@mposvsit.ci6bzozvzhi4.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1525:MPOS
>        [echo]       ${writable.data.user}=ubuntu
>        [echo]       ${writable.data.group}=
>        [echo]
>        [echo] Sleeping, take your time...
>       [sleep] sleeping for 10000 milliseconds
>
> init2: [available] Unable to find file
>   /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/etc/server.env
>
> init3:
>        [java] Executing '/opt/IBM/InstallationManager/eclipse/jre_7.0.9010.20151006_1234/jre/bin/java'
>   with arguments:
>        [java] '-classpath'
>        [java] '/opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/WorklightServer/worklight-ant-deployer.jar'
>        [java] 'com.ibm.worklight.config.helper.appserver.WASLibertyFindPort'
>        [java] '/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty//usr/servers/mfp'
>        [java] 
>        [java] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
>        [java] not part of the command.
>        [java] Output redirected to /opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/WorklightServer/WASLibertyFindPort.out
>        [java] Error redirected to property: WASLibertyFindPort.err [available] Found file: WASLibertyFindPort.out
>        [echo] WASLibertyFindPort => appserver.was85liberty.protocol = http
>        [echo] WASLibertyFindPort => appserver.was85liberty.port = 9080    [delete] Deleting:
>   /opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/WorklightServer/WASLibertyFindPort.out
>
> init:
>
> configure-appcenter-database: [configuredatabaseIMWrapper] Logging
>   output of task  to file
>   /root/.mobilefirst_platform_server/configuration-logs/configureDatabase_ApplicationCenter_2016_01_17_15_39_22.log
>   [configuredatabaseIMWrapper] Checking connectivity to
>   ApplicationCenter database with user/schema 'WLADMIN'...
>   [configuredatabaseIMWrapper] Connection to ApplicationCenter database
>   with user/schema 'WLADMIN' succeeded. [configuredatabaseIMWrapper]
>   Getting the version of ApplicationCenter database ...
>   [configuredatabaseIMWrapper] Test if the table APPCNTR_VERSION exists
>   and if yes, get the version. [configuredatabaseIMWrapper] Table
>   APPCNTR_VERSION exists, reading its value...   [antcall] Exiting
>   /opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/WorklightServer/post-install.xml.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   /opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/WorklightServer/post-install.xml:332:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/WorklightServer/post-install.xml:2096:
>   The SQL query SELECT APPCNTR_VERSION FROM APPCNTR_VERSION returned no
>   rows, but expected 1 row.     at
>   com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.database.ConfigureDatabaseTask$1.call(ConfigureDatabaseTask.java:1863)
>     at
>   com.ibm.worklight.config.util.database.DatabaseUtil.withConnection(DatabaseUtil.java:420)
>     at
>   com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.database.ConfigureDatabaseTask.getSQLQueryResult(ConfigureDatabaseTask.java:1852)
>     at
>   com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.database.ConfigureDatabaseTask.getDatabaseVersionApplicationCenter(ConfigureDatabaseTask.java:1045)
>     at
>   com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.database.ConfigureDatabaseTask.getDatabaseVersion(ConfigureDatabaseTask.java:855)
>     at
>   com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.database.ConfigureDatabaseTask.checkDatabasesConnectivity(ConfigureDatabaseTask.java:781)
>     at
>   com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.database.ConfigureDatabaseTask.execute(ConfigureDatabaseTask.java:289)
>     at
>   com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.database.ConfigureDatabaseIMWrapper.execute(ConfigureDatabaseIMWrapper.java:159)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
>     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)  at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)  at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)  at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)    at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
>
> Total time: 20 seconds

***What I've tried:***

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31981942/ibm-mobilefirst-installation-error-post-install-xml), I've tried to change the /etc/hosts file ip to the host IP accordingly (got this ip from ifconfig):

[image]

**Updated**
IBM Installation Manager is able to detect the 2 server instances with the name "mfp" and "analytics":

[image]

ANT script property:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to log, it sounds like some kind of bug, during AppCenter database tables check (database exists, successful connection verified) - 
"The SQL query SELECT APPCNTR_VERSION FROM APPCNTR_VERSION returned no rows, but expected 1". Instead of exiting it needs to actually create those tables. Ideally you should open a PMR to IBM support with this.

But you can try to overcome this issue in 2 ways.

1. By trying to execute SQL script manually within your DB and then re-run installer. Most probably it will go through fluently afterwards. For oracle file called create-appcenter-oracle.sql and it is located somewhere under /opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/ApplicationCenter
2. By setting up Application Center manually (executing sql script on database, installing/moving war files and configuring server) and then deselect checkbox to install appcenter during installation with Installation Manager.

Follow instructions on Knowledge center for your DB
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/c_manually_configuring_databases_for_ac.html

You can also get some insights from here (prior to lab 8.3) https://mfp.help/appcenter-on-bluemix/

Hopefully installer will afterwards go fine for MFP Server and Analytics database, otherwize you will need to setup those sings also manually using ant scripts.

Comment: Hi @Andrii Vasylchenko, where can I get this "create-appcenter-oracle.sql" script? There's only "failed-install.log" in my "/opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server" directory. I didn't run the sql script when setting up the database.

Comment: The script is in the directory "<mfp install dir>/ApplicationCenter/databases". Before installing appcenter you must configure the db as explained here : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/t_ac_create_db_ant_tasks.html

Comment: Yup got it @Andrii Vasylchenko. It's in /opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/ApplicationCenter/databases. In order to have this file, I need to select NO in the Application Center Screen for the installation to complete as recommended by Olivier Zembri. Thank you so much.

Comment: Rerunning the installer after running the SQL script manually still return the same error log :( Running ant scripts does not work as well, since it doesn't detect my server instance...

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it is possible to install Application Center either manually or using Ant tasks.

So you may try choosing not installing Application Center in Installation Manager by checking radio button "No" when prompting to do so. This way, Installation Manager will certainly completes the installation successfully in your target directory "/opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server".

Afterwards, you may create the Application Center database using the script create-appcenter-oracle.sql that should have been installed in
"/opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/ApplicationCenter/configuration-samples"

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_setting_up_your_oracle_database_manually_for_ac.html?lang=en

After the Application Center database is created, the next step is to deploy Application Center to your Liberty profile using Ant task for example

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/t_ac_deploy_cons_serv_ant_tasks.html?lang=en

Comment: Hi @Oliver Zembri, I'm getting this error while running the ant script, it seems like it can't detect my server instance: "/opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/ApplicationCenter/configuration-samples/wkAnt/configure-appcenter-liberty-oracle.xml:74: Element <server> inside <websphereApplicationServer> inside <applicationserver> inside <installApplicationCenter>: attribute 'name' value 'mfp' is invalid: A server named 'mfp' does not exist. The existing servers are: []"

Comment: According to the error you get, it seems that you haven't created a Liberty server yet. You should first create a Liberty server with the name "mfp" before running the installation of Application Center.
From the bin directory of your Liberty installation, execute command :
server create mfp

Comment: I've already created a server instance with the name "mfp" and another instance name "analytics"...The ANT is not able to detect these 2 existing servers. On the other hand, IBM Installation Manager is able to detect the server with the name "mfp" and "analytics" as shown in the image above. This behaviour really contradicts each other.